# RecyclerView does not expand its height when an item is added on adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager, android-tablayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have a layout containing a `RecyclerView` and a layout for handling showing more items. When one or more items are received from hitting the *"Show more"* button the adapter is notified and the items are added on the RecyclerView. **But** the problem is, that the RecyclerView's **height** after an item has been added is not expanded.

This layout is part of a fragment contained in a `ViewPager` under a `CollapsingToolbarLayout`.

The structure of the fragment's layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:background="#f5f5f5">

<com.github.rahatarmanahmed.cpv.CircularProgressView
    android:id="@+id/progress_view"
    android:layout_width="45dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    app:cpv_animAutostart="true"
    app:cpv_indeterminate="true"
    app:cpv_thickness="4dp"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/list_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/reviews_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/show_more_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="#eee">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/show_more_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Show More"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"/>

        <com.github.rahatarmanahmed.cpv.CircularProgressView
            android:id="@+id/show_more_progress_view"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            app:cpv_animAutostart="true"
            app:cpv_indeterminate="true"
            app:cpv_thickness="3dp"/>

    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

And the current state is something like this:

[image: State]

- And the black part of image is the device's available height.

Comment: Have you tried to call "requestLayout" on the RecyclerView?

Comment: Yeah, didn't work either..

Comment: @gkanellis Were you able to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Check this modified layout.
Adding weight to recyclerview and the button wil make it fixed in particular position.Hope it works for you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:background="#f5f5f5">

<com.github.rahatarmanahmed.cpv.CircularProgressView
    android:id="@+id/progress_view"
    android:layout_width="45dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    app:cpv_animAutostart="true"
    app:cpv_indeterminate="true"
    app:cpv_thickness="4dp"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/list_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/reviews_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.9"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/show_more_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:background="#eee">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/show_more_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Show More"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"/>

        <com.github.rahatarmanahmed.cpv.CircularProgressView
            android:id="@+id/show_more_progress_view"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            app:cpv_animAutostart="true"
            app:cpv_indeterminate="true"
            app:cpv_thickness="3dp"/>

    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. change the layout_height of linearlayout to match_parrent.
2. change the layout_height of recyclerview to match_parrent.
3. **change your recyclerviews item's height to wrap_content.**

try this

Comment: Setting the layout_height of linearlayout to match_parrent didn't work. If I set the he layout_height of recyclerview to match_parrent then the "Show more" button is hidden due to the LinearLayout's behavior.

Comment: so change the linearlayout to relative layout.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/list_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
```

to

```
 <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/list_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
```

Also change the Recyclerview height to match_parent

Comment: Didn't work. Still recyclerView is only scrollable is the area that the first item's where added.

Comment: Also change the Recycler view height to match_parent

Answer (score 0):

Change your `LinearLayout` to a `RelativeLayout`, anchor `FrameLayout` to bottom parent and `RecyclerView` above your `FrameLayout` as follow:

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/list_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/reviews_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/show_more_container" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/show_more_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#eee">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/show_more_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Show More"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"/>

        <com.github.rahatarmanahmed.cpv.CircularProgressView
            android:id="@+id/show_more_progress_view"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Change `RecyclerView` height to `match_parent`